# Can a PDF downloaded by my iOS app be viewed by iBooks or any other application?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

Right now, the PDFs I download on my app are being stored in the app's document directory and can be retrieved only within the app. Is there any way to store the PDF files in the common documents directory that can be accessed by other apps?

If not, is there a way of storing my downloaded PDFs in other apps' documents directory (let's say iBooks), so that it will always be stored in iBooks.

If there are any ways, please elaborate.

Comment: Suppose are you download PDF from email then you get on iBook ?

Comment: Apple has not provided any access to other application document directory .So i afraid this is not possible .

Comment: Yes you are right so we cant access any application document directory to any other application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "commun documents directory" on iOS, each App is launched in is own sandbox and cannot access the files from other app directly.
I suggest you to check the [iOS File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) guide from Apple in order to understand better what's happening behind the scenes.

You can still use an `UIActivityController` in your code to perform an export of your pdf file to iBooks or any app accepting this kind of file, but it requires some user interaction.